# Adding Eigen to PlatformIO

Tags: eigen, platformio, teensy

I'm having trouble adding Eigen (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) to the PlatformIO for use with the Teensy 4.1.

What is the proper procedure for adding a library to PlatformIO when it's not in the registry? I tried following this: https://community.platformio.org/t/how-to-include-arduino-library-in-platformio/15146 but it didn't solve my issue.

Just looking if anyone has used the Eigen library with PlatformIO and how they installed it.

Comment: I did compile the library just fine using my regular mingw C++ compiler in VS Code no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I did get it to work.

In lib on PlatformIO create a NEW folder, like "Eigen_Main".

Download the Eigen Zip (use latest stable version).

Extract the "Eigen" folder and place it into Eigen_Main.

Also in Eigen_Main add this header as "Eigen.h":

```
// Credits:   @rpavlik for writing this header.
// Note:  "Importantly, it includes a header to both indicate to the Arduino IDE
//         that this library should be used, and set up the preprocessor environment
//         so the ample #define lines in the Arduino and AVR libraries don't wreak havoc with Eigen.

// Disable debug asserts.
#define EIGEN_NO_DEBUG 1

// Hint to number of registers
#define EIGEN_ARCH_DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_REGISTERS 16

#ifdef A0
# define NEED_A0_RESTORED A0
# undef A0
#endif
#ifdef A1
# define NEED_A1_RESTORED A1
# undef A1
#endif
#ifdef B0
# define NEED_B0_RESTORED B0
# undef B0
#endif
#ifdef B1
# define NEED_B1_RESTORED B1
# undef B1
#endif

namespace std {
    struct nothrow_t;
}


// Include main EIGEN Core header
#include <Eigen/Core>


#ifdef NEED_A0_RESTORED
# define A0 NEED_A0_RESTORED
# undef NEED_A0_RESTORED
#endif
#ifdef NEED_A1_RESTORED
# define A1 NEED_A1_RESTORED
# undef NEED_A1_RESTORED
#endif
#ifdef NEED_B0_RESTORED
# define B0 NEED_B0_RESTORED
# undef NEED_B0_RESTORED
#endif
#ifdef NEED_B1_RESTORED
# define B1 NEED_B1_RESTORED
# undef NEED_B1_RESTORED
#endif
```

Your platform IO project should have:

```
.pio
.vscode
include
lib
  -Eigen_Main
    -Eigen
    -Eigen.h
src
test
platformio.ini
```

Comment: Btw, Platformio supports ArduinoEigen:

    lib_deps = hideakitai/ArduinoEigen@^0.3.0